# Cake PHP Select to Dropdown

Tags: php, forms, cakephp-3.0

I'm newbie with CakePHP and need some help.  I baked my first application but I'm not able to make it behave as I want.

I have two tables, players and teams, and a join table players_teams.  The form displays fine.  But I would like to change the select area to a drop down menu.  The player could have many teams over time (I added a from and a to date columns to the join table for that), but I would like the player to be assigned to one team at the moment it is created.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('player_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('player_last_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('player_number');
        echo $this->Form->input('player_birthday');
        echo $this->Form->input('teams._ids', [ 'multiple' => false, 'options' => $teams,]);
    ?>
```

It does not change to a dropdow. I have also tried this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('teams._ids',  ['type' => 'select', 'multiple' => false, 'options' => $teams, 'empty' => true]);
```

This last one change the select to a dropdown, but whatever I select doesn't go to the database.

Heres the Controller for Players:

```
public function add()
{
    $player = $this->Players->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $player = $this->Players->patchEntity($player, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Players->save($player)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The player has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The player could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $teams = $this->Players->Teams->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('player', 'teams'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['player']);
}
```

Here's the PlayersTeamController:

```
public function add()
{
    $playersTeam = $this->PlayersTeams->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $playersTeam = $this->PlayersTeams->patchEntity($playersTeam, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->PlayersTeams->save($playersTeam)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The players team has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The players team could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $players = $this->PlayersTeams->Players->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $teams = $this->PlayersTeams->Teams->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('playersTeam', 'players', 'teams'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['playersTeam']);
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[The Cakebook: 3.0](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs)

Have you tried:

```
echo $this->Form->select(
  'teams'
  ,$teams->toArray()
  ,[
    'multiple' => false,
    'class' => '_ids',
    'empty' => true
  ]
);
```

Comment: I get this: Error: Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array

Comment: @MiguelCedenoAgamez i don't actually know anything about CakePHP; i'm just a quick Googler. sorry

Comment: Same as the original, it changes to a dropdown (in a weird way this time), but it doesn't save the team id to the junction table.

Comment: @MiguelCedenoAgamez can you post the generated html code? it might help

Comment: <select name="teams[_ids]"><option value="multiple"></option><optgroup label="options"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></optgroup><option value="empty">1</option></select>

Comment: no luck, it only added and _ids option to the dropdown

Comment: @MiguelCedenoAgamez see update (3rd time the charm!) i actually read the docs for select this time (go to the linked page in the answer and do a ctrl+f for `::select`

Comment: It now shows the dropdown, but it does not save the relation.  I will do more research.  I think it will be related to the controller itself.

Comment: good luck. don't forget to post the solution when you find it!

Answer (score 0):

Just resemble the required data structure yourself, that is

```
[
    'teams' => [
        '_ids' => [
            // single id here
        ]
    ]
]
```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting BelongsToMany Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data)**

## Proper, array-ish element name

You can do that by for example specifying the proper element `name` attribute value, like

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'teams',
    [
        'name' => 'teams[_ids][0]'
        //'options' => $teams // this is optional when following the conventions
    ]
);
```

which will automatically choose a `select` type, based on the options.

You will need some additional logic to prevent further selections to be injected, as an array-ish name like `teams[_ids][0]` would allow that without the Security component being able to detect such tampering. This can be done using validation, or by preparing the data in the `Model.beforeMarshal` event.

Here's a validation example

```
public function validationCreate(Validator $validator) {
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);

    $teamsValidator = (new Validator())
        ->requirePresence('_ids')
        ->notEmpty('_ids')
        ->add('_ids', 'valid', [
            'rule' => function($value) {
                return is_array($value) && count($value) === 1;
            }
        ]);

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('teams')
        ->notEmpty('teams')
        ->addNested('teams', $tagsValidator);

    return $validator;
}
```

```
$player = $this->Players->patchEntity($player, $this->request->data, [
    'validate' => 'create'
]);
```

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Validation and patchEntity](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validation-and-patchentity)**
- **[API > \Cake\Validation\Validator::addNested()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html#_addNested)**

## Custom, single value element name

Another options would be to specify a non array-ish name, combined with preparing the data in the `Model.beforeMarshal` event, like

```
echo $this->Form->input('teams', ['name' => 'initial_team']);
```

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (isset($data['initial_team'])) {
        $data['teams'] = [
            '_ids' => [
                $data['initial_team']
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**

## Note

Both will retain the CakePHP magic like the marshaller converting the passed `_ids` into entities so that the associations are being saved properly, automatically picking up the input options, automatically choosing the input type, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you have made proper [associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html), you can save directly from the PlayersController. PlayersTeamController isn't needed at all. When you patch the newly created player [entity](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-entities) with the request data, associated table data will be automatically get into it and saved by the entity [save()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations) command as its one level of association only.